# how to create a column of average number of the whole table

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my problem,
so basically I want to add a new column with the Avg of the data column for the table:

input

```
number  data    
1       4   
2       5   
3       6   
4       7
```

output

```
number  data    avg_data .  
1       4       5.5 .  
2       5       5.5 . 

3       6       5.5 . 

4       7       5.5 .
```

Comment: include a sub query in your select.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a sub-select on the `SELECT` statement using `SUM` and `COUNT`:

```
SELECT *,
  (SELECT SUM(data) / COUNT(*) FROM table_name) AS avg_data
FROM table_name
```

... or using `AVG`:

```
SELECT *,
  (SELECT AVG(data) FROM table_name) AS avg_data
FROM table_name
```

You can also use [create a view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html) so you only need to query the view in future:

```
-- create the view
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT *,
  (SELECT SUM(data) / COUNT(*) FROM table_name) AS avg_data
FROM table_name

-- SELECT from view
SELECT * FROM view_name
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5237a3449b47e28f02c3dd010d9f35d5)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cross join between you  table and the sub-query for avg

```
SELECT m.number, m.data , t.avg_data 
FROM my_table m
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT avg(data) avg_data 
  FROM my_table
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8+, you would use window functions:

```
select t.*, avg(data) over () as avg_data
from t;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *,(SELECT AVG(dat) FROM tablename) FROM tablename
```

try  this one